# Multiple PHP image upload, only uploads first image selected

Tags: php, file, upload

I have set up a multiple file upload form. However when I select multiple images and click upload, only the first image uploads and not the array of images? Cheers.

```
<?php
// Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
        $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
        $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
        $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

        // Verify file size - 20MB maximum
        $maxsize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
        if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

        // Verify MYME type of the file
        if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
            // Check whether file exists before uploading it
            if(file_exists("upload/" . $filename)){
                echo $filename . " is already exists.";
            } else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filename);
                echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
            } 
        } else{
            echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
        }
    } else{
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: because your code does not iterate over the files array

Comment: okay.. How do I go about doing this...

Comment: you have to give the uploading in a for loop.. this one wont work..also the file name should be given as an array

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you need to do:

- Input name must be be defined as an array i.e. name="inputName[]"
- Input element must have multiple="multiple" or just multiple
- In your PHP file use the syntax "$_FILES['inputName']['param'][index]"
- Make sure to look for empty file names and paths, the array might contain empty strings. Use array_filter() before count.
- Here is a down and dirty example (showing just relevant code)

HTML:

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP:

```
//$files = array_filter($_FILES['upload']['name']); //something like that to be used before processing files.

// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    //Make sure we have a file path
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

          //Handle other code here

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps out!

Answer (score 1):

I have done some changes in your code use it.may help you and also please check

```
<input type="file" multiple>



  if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
        $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"][$i];
        $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"][$i];

        // Verify file extension
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

       // Verify file size - 20MB maximum
       $maxsize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
       if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

       // Verify MYME type of the file
       if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
        // Check whether file exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists("upload/" . $filename)){
            echo $filename . " is already exists.";
        } else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i], "upload/" . $filename);
            echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
        } 
    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
  }
} else{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
}
```

} ?>

Comment: Why should the OP ___use it___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.